# Windows Phone app to upload videos to a web browser

Tags: video

Is there an app to upload a video directly to a cloud storage location, so end users can view it in a web browser?

We are a manufacturing company and the engineers often make videos of broken down manufacturing machines, to demonstrate to the suppliers the issue with the machines they have supplied.

Answer (score 4):

Services like OneDrive, Dropbox and Box have their own dedicated Windows Phone apps for uploading and downloading files. Not all cloud services support Windows Phone but more and more are as time goes on.

- [Box](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/box/9wzdncrfj13s)
- [OneDrive](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/onedrive/9wzdncrfj1p3)
- [Dropbox](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/dropbox/9wzdncrfj0pk)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer my question :-)  Do you have any experience using the apps? and if so, which would be the easiest to use for a novice "end user" to upload and share with someone?

Comment: I've used both Box and SkyDrive.  SkyDrive is a bit better for novice users since it's built by Microsoft and follows the Windows Phone design paradigms the best so it works similar to how the built-in phone apps work.  I personally use Box more though since I have more friends, collaborators, and colleagues that use Box.  Also, be sure to accept the response if it answers your question so that others may benefit from the information here.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an app for Windows Phone that records video and uploads full resolution video to your OneDrive or Dropbox.

[Video Diary](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/video-diary/9wzdncrdmgbf) free

[Video Journal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/video-journal/9wzdncrdmgjf) paid with forward facing camera support and social network sharing of the uploaded video

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me quick. I like the sound it.  Is there a way to share the video directly from the app so the end user can see it in a webbrowser?

Comment: I've tested the apps on with the user and the 1st video uploaded to sky drive and could be viewed in the web browser.  The 2nd video uploaded but when viewed in skydrive it wanted the user to download the video (not view in the web browsers). I prefer the user to display in web browser so it can be viewed on any device.

Comment: Great App. Just a couple of suggestions to simplify the upload process for our users 1. A direct upload from the video recording screen (instead of separate screen).  2. Auto share with other users. At the moment the user has to open web browser on his PC to share it through SkyDrive.  Thanks, keep up the good work

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The link you share from the app is actually the video file itself! Skydrive doesnt force them to watch the video like YouTube. I think you change browser setting and tell it how to handle an .mp4 video file.

Comment: In reference to watching the video through a web browser. I've changed the folder settings and no difference.  From reading internet posts, it looks like codec issues (the way the videos saved) is the cause.  People saving the video in WMV or mp4 on different devices have no problems. Does you program use the standard windows encoding or is there special ones for windows phone? Ive not coded for windows phone so dont know a lot about the platform.

Comment: You've nailed it. Windows Phone mp4's are different than others. The biggest request from my users is that they get the raw video without compression or alteration, so that's what you're getting. Direct video from the hardware, using the OS's codec.